# MX Records and A Records Updated But Email Addresses Can Still Send Email

Tags: mx-record, cname-record

I have updated the MX Records, the A records, the Z records and the cname for a particular domain but the emails registered with the hosting provider can still send email. The changes have definitely propagated since the mail boxes can no longer receive email.

Why can these email addresses still send outgoing email? The test messages I've sent to my google account say "encryption:  name_of_hosting_provider.com did not encrypt this message".

I need these email addresses disabled, unable to send or receive email.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please give us more details.

Comment: Are you trying to stop someone sending email from an account by changing where the accounts are held?

Comment: Drifter104 Yes, you nailed it.

Comment: Short answer - You can't. It doesn't matter if you get that service closed down or not. If someone wants to send email as a domain they can. The most you can do is try and protect the domain with things like SPF records but even then if they aren't checked for at the other side it doesn't matter

Comment: joeqwerty: The domain name and hosting account were registered separately and I no longer have control over the hosting account.

Since I was going to get new hosting for the domain anyway, I thought changing the MX records would disable the email addresses that were registered with the old hosting provider (because their MX records will be obsolete) but that did not happen. Now I am trying to figure out why this didn't happened and if there are any other methods I could use to avoid getting this domain blacklisted for spamming

Comment: Drifter104: If I create the same email account on another server (lets say example@example.com) with a different password, will example@example.com still be accessible from the old host using the old password?

Comment: MX records designate which hosts receive email for a given domain. They have nothing to do with which hosts can send email for a given domain. SPF records designate which hosts may send email for a given domain. Additionally, neither has anything to do with email accounts or mailboxes.

Comment: Yes - If you think about it why wouldn't it be able to?

Comment: @joeqwerty One would have thought that the receiving server would check if the MX Record matched the address of the originating server or not. Apparently they don't. Reminds me of how you could spoof emails without a password using telnet back in the day.

Thank you for your help. Any pointers on how to set up SPF? I haven't looked into the infrastructure of emails in a very long time.

Comment: @Drifter104 That does not seem to work either, I can use webmail on the old and new servers to access the same account with two different passwords and send out emails...that does not make a lot of sense tbh

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to adress your question and some of your comments in this answer. You have a misunderstanding of how email works and how hosting providers work.

`I have updated the MX Records, the A records, the Z records and the cname for a particular domain but the emails registered with the hosting provider can still send email`

Of course they can. The MX and A records have nothing to do with what user accounts and email addresses I can set up on my email server. I can set up an email server for microsoft.com and create a user account and email address for bgates@microsoft.com and use that to send email to my hearts content. Whether or not a receiving server accepts these emails is entirely up to them. If they check for and use SPF, DKIM and DMARC then chances are my email will be rejected. That doesn't negate the fact that I can set this up if I so choose. There's no universal database or authority that says "Hey, you can't set up an email server for Microsoft and send email from bgates@microsoft.com!". Of course, I can't receive any email to my bgates@microsoft.com email address... because I'm not really Bill Gates and I don't control the MX record for the microsoft.com domain and therefore can't designate my email server as the MX record for the microsoft.com domain. The MX record doesn't prevent me from setting up my email server for the microsoft.com domain, it only prevents me from receiving email for the microsoft.com domain (and in most cases will prevent my email from bgates@microsoft.com from being accepted. It doesn't prevent me from sending it, but most email servers will reject it upon receiving it).

`Since I was going to get new hosting for the domain anyway, I thought changing the MX records would disable the email addresses that were registered with the old hosting provider (because their MX records will be obsolete) but that did not happen`

MX records have nothing to do with user accounts or mailboxes. MX records designate which host(s) receive email for a given domain. They're not used to validate user accounts or email addresses. Changing the MX record means that the old email server will no longer receive email for that domain but it doesn't mean that those user accounts and mailboxes are now magically disabled. They are completely internal to the hosting provider and unrelated to DNS. Email from those user accounts and email addresses can still be sent. It's up to the receiving server to decide whether to accept them or not (based on SPF, DKIM and DMARC).

`One would have thought that the receiving server would check if the MX Record matched the address of the originating server or not. Apparently they don't`

They're completely independent accounts hosted at two entirely different providers. The fact that they share the same usernames and email addresses is meaningless. Furthermore, MX records designate which host(s) receive email for a given domain while SPF records designate which host(s) send email for a given domain. These hosts are not always and not necessarily the same. So what if I had one host that receives email for my domain and another host that sends email for my domain? Imagine what would happen if your email server checked the MX record for my domain when I sent you an email and your server said "Hey, this server sending me email from joe@mydomain.com isn't the same server that receives email for joe@mydomain.com, I'm going to reject this email!"? My configuration is perfectly valid (an quite common) but your server rejects my email under the false pretense that the server that receives email for a domain (MX) should be the same server that sends email for a domain (SPF).

Comment: Thank you, that was extremely helpful.

I set up an SPF rule of type TXT with the value "v=spf1 a mx ip4:xx.xx.xx.xx -all", hopefully that will work.

I was confusing everything with everything else. Uptil 2007, you could telnet into Hotmail and Yahoo servers and send emails from any account with no verification whatsoever, Gmail was the only exception. By 2008, this had changed and no one let you spoof emails like that. I mistakenly thought webmail would behave in a similar fashion.

Google kept returning results on how to block emails which was pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

The MX record is telling the other email server the IP or hostname of the email server. Your client accounts need to be deleted/removed or disabled. Depending on your host provider your setting may vary. Just login to your cPanel and go into your mail accounts and either delete the account or change the user/account password. If you are hosting the mail server you can go in manually and disable etc. Hope this was of some use...

Comment: Sadly, the problem is that I don't have the password for the old hosting account and the person who does have the password is who has to be kept away from these accounts.

Comment: @SyedAliIrtazaKazmi You need to contact the Hosting company directly online. They should be able to help you further!

Comment: I did, they told me if I didn't have the password they couldn't/wouldn't do much.Initially kept telling me about spam hammer for some reason though

Comment: @SyedAliIrtazaKazmi Do you know if the Webmaster (The person) ever sent any of the information to anyone else?

Comment: They did not, at least not since they changed the password